# Is Ubuntu Missing The Shared WiFi Connection That Kubuntu Comes Preinstalled With?

Tags: wireless, drivers, kubuntu, android

I just started using Linux a couple of months ago. I started with Lubuntu and later switched to Kubuntu, which seemed nice and all except for its constant slowness.
But on Kubuntu, i was able to share Internet to my android phone by opening the network connections, selecting New, then selecting WiFi(shared) [Which doesn't seem to be available on Ubuntu 14.04.

Ubuntu  14 only provides me with WiFi.And when I go ahead and create an adhoc connection, my Android device is unable to detect it due to a restriction in the android wpa_supplicant file.

I have tried many solutions here on ask but non seems to work out.

As I have already said, on Kubuntu all i had to do was select WIFI(shared) option and input my password and its being detected by my Android phone.
My Laptops internal WiFi chip(PRO/Wireless 3945ABG) never worked on Kubuntu. So i used to use my USB WiFi dongle(zydas zd1211) and it worked perfectly.

So could it be that the drivers Kubuntu was using for the USB dongle supported shared connection but that of Ubuntu doesn't?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
In terminal run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot
```

Once installed, execute below command to configure your wifi hotspot:

```
sudo ap-hotspot configure
```

After configuration start the wireless hotspot

```
sudo ap-hotspot start
```

To stop the wireless hotspot, execute this command

```
sudo ap-hotspot stop
```